# Gap statistic method with alternative distance measures

Tags: r, clustering

How can one adapt `cluster::clusGap` to work with an alternative distance measure such as Gower's distances? Does the output generalise to every clustering algorithm, or should virtually the clustering algorithm also be a hyperparameter?

Comment: Are you asking how to use the ```clusGap``` function for this or how to do this in R generally, or do you also want to know how to do this theoretically and whether it makes sense for other distance measures?

Comment: ```clusGap``` has an argument ```FUNcluster``` which needs to be specified if you want a different clustering method. So this *is* a hyperparameter.

Comment: Regarding using the ```clusGap``` function as it is with other distances I'm rather pessimistic. The calculation of the gap statistic is not set up for this, if I understand things correctly. It may well be you'd have to write your own code, but somebody else may know better.

Comment: Indeed, I don't think `clusGap` is suitable with other distance metrics such as Gower's distances. For example, I cannot perform `pam` with a precomputed distance matrix and use `clusGap`.